# Opmac Footnotes with no newline

Tags: tex-core, opmac

I'm using OPMAC footnote macros in Plain TeX.

I am trying to format multiple footnotes on one page so they are next to each and not positioned on a new line.  At the moment it formats like

[image: this]

But I need to something like:

1 Supply sunt. 2 there was. 3 unus....

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example which produces the output you show.